# Importing records from a CSV and writing at the same time to same CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I need to be able to compare two columns of every row in a CSV with my own database.

For example, a row looks like this:

```
Headers => "Zipcode", "HouseNumber"
Row 1   => "5435 ZX", "43"
```

First I need to find a Company in my own database, based on zipcode and housenumber, and, if this returns true, then I need to import the rest of the columns in this row. I know how to solve this.

But, I also need to be able to keep track of the imported rows, because I need to split up the total records in small chunks, so I need to add an extra field to every row once imported.

To summarize:

How can I add an extra field ("imported") to every row once imported in the following loop:

```
CSV.foreach('reviews.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
   Review.create(row.to_hash)
end
```

Comment: In re-reading the question, the line "I need to split up the total records in small chunks" sticks out to me - why do you need to do this?  Can you give more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the simplest thing to do would be to maintain the "imported" state in a separate hash, like so:

```
imported = {}
CSV.read('reviews.csv').each_with_index do |row, line|
  if <your condition> && !imported[line]
    # create model
    imported[line] = true
  end
end
```

Then just keep that hash around until you need to read the next block, and re-run.  The `&& !imported[line]` bit will prevent reading a line twice.

If that's not what you're looking for, you'll need to clarify your question a bit.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet will create the `Review` if you can find the `Company`. You'll have to clean it up to match it to the correct attribute names for the `companies` table.

```
CSV.foreach('reviews.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
   Review.create(row.to_hash) if Company.where("Zipcode = ? and HouseNumber = ?", 
       row.Zipcode, row.HouseNumber)
end
```

To add an additional column, to the following:

```
CSV.foreach('reviews.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
   if company = Company.where("Zipcode = ? and HouseNumber = ?", 
       row.Zipcode, row.HouseNumber)
   row[:imported] = true
   Review.create(row.to_hash) 
end
```

This assumes the `imported` column exists in your table.

I think we may need more information to give you a more complete answer, but the ideas here should get you close.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but row[:imported] = true ( or a string) doesn't seem to work. I use this in a rake task, but the "imported" fields in a don't change.

Comment: This is why I was saying we need more info. Can you post that model code?

Comment: It's not the model code that breaks... Even this fails:
CSV.foreach('reviews.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  row[:imported] = "true"
end

Comment: @Laurens, are you under the impression that setting the value `row[:imported] = true` should _change the file_?  That is not at all what this is doing.  He's adding the imported flag to your new Review model.  I don't think that's what you want done.  You need to persist the imported-ness of each row somehow for future import runs.  My answer will do that in an in-memory hash.  If you need it in the CSV file itself, you'll need to read in the CSV to rows, do your import and set the flag, then save the file out again.  Messy!